# Getting number of Direct Conversions and Assisted conversions for Landing pages using google analytics api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am new to google analytics so please forgive if the question is not described properly.
I want to show the performance of landing pages by showing number of assisted conversions and direct conversions. 
I want the information like this:

Landing page - www.xyz.com/article
No of Direct Conversions - 8
No of Assisted Conversions - 15

I tried to use Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API api. But I could'nt find a way to show the conversions according to landing pages. Is there a way to get information like this using google analytics api?

Answer (score 1):

Landing page dimension is not available in Multi-channel reporting API that is quite limited compared to what's available in the Analytics UI. So, basically, you can't get this from API.
You might find the list of all the available dimensions in the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets)

Comment: Indeed there are very little solutions to export the Lnading page data on a regular basis. Even the CSV export in the GUI cannot be automated for daily email reporting for example. GA360 customers can get a scheduled Unsampled Report. The MCF API doc is there https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3

Answer (score -1):

**CORRECTION:** This answer is incorrect, there is an MCF API that you can use to grab data from MCF reporting. The setup for this kind of API reporting is very similar to Core Reporting API. You learn something new every day! Disregard this answer.

---

**Original answer:** Unfortunately multi-channel funnel reporting information is not available through the Reporting API. The likely reason for this is the information in those funnel reports are calculated by Google and the Reporting API only spits out information as is.

You should be able to pull direct conversions however and you can do it a number of ways. Either add the `ga:channelGrouping` dimension and use a filter where `ga:channelGrouping=@Direct` or you can add the Direct traffic segment ID `"segmentId": "gaid::-37"`.

Here's a full list of the different segmentId's that you can apply to your report requests: https://stuifbergen.com/2018/02/google-analytics-api-built-in-segments-the-complete-list/

Since you're relatively new to Google Analytics, I would also suggest checking out some open source code I've used for batch reporting using the Reporting API:
https://github.com/jessfeliciano/aggregateGoogleAnalyticsReporting/blob/master/objectQueryWithFilter.js

**CORRECTION:** This answer is incorrect, there is an MCF API that you can use to grab data from MCF reporting. The setup for this kind of API reporting is very similar to Core Reporting API. You learn something new every day!

Comment: It's not in the GA Core reporting API but in the MCF API

Comment: I never new the MCF API existed, this is actually super helpful for me, thanks!